# How to convert output in traditional format into text and replace spaces with *?

Tags: string-manipulation, traditional-form

From a following program (part of a longer program) I will get a recurrence in an elegant format.

```
 sold =
 {624, -1490, 1244, -430, 52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6648, 13539, -9945, 
 3117, -351, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12384, -22716, 15216, -4416, 468, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3456, -8672, 6752, -2032, 208, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 53760, -86912, 47552, -10624, 832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
 maxdenom = 624; maxdeg = 10; j = 4;
 strecur = ""; ikoef = 0;
 Do[sign = 0; dejmin = 0; numpol = Factor[Sum[ikoef++; 
  If[sold[[ikoef]] != 0, sign = Sign[sold[[ikoef]]]];
  sold[[ikoef]]*n^i, {i, 0, maxdeg}]];
  If[ord == 0, signan = sign; 
  If[signan < 0, numpol = -numpol; sign = 1;]];
  If[ord > 0 && signan > 0, If[sign == 1, dejmin = 1, 
  If[sign != 0, numpol = Factor[-numpol]; sign = 1];];];
  If[ord > 0 && signan < 0, 
  If[sign == -1, dejmin = 1; numpol = Factor[-numpol]; sign = 1];];
  strpol = ToString[TraditionalForm[numpol*a[n - ord]]];
  If[sign == 1, If[ord < 2, znam = "", znam = "+"], 
  If[ord > 1, znam = "+", znam = ""]];
  If[dejmin == 1, znam = "-"];
  If[sign != 0 && strpol != "0", strecur = strecur <> znam <> strpol];
  If[ord == 0, strecur = strecur <> "="];, {ord, 0, j}];
 Print[strecur]
```

[image]

How to replace spaces with `*` in the TraditionalForm output ?
I can export this (manually) as "plain text"

```
 2 (n-1) (2 n-3) (13 n^2-75 n+104) a(n)=3 (117 n^4-1039 n^3+3315 n^2-4513 n+2216) a(n-1)-12 (39 n^4-368 n^3+1268 n^2-1893 n+1032) a(n-2)-16 (n-4) (13 n^3-75 n^2+122 n-54) a(n-3)-64 (n-5) (n-4) (13 n^2-49 n+42) a(n-4)
```

and replace all spaces with `*` manually in an external editor. But I want to do this in Mathematica and print it (with `*`) inside the program. I need a string

```
 "2*(n-1)*(2*n-3)*(13*n^2-75*n+104)*a(n)=3*(117*n^4-1039*n^3+3315*n^2-4513*n+2216)*a(n-1)-12*(39*n^4-368*n^3+1268*n^2-1893*n+1032)*a(n-2)-16*(n-4)*(13*n^3-75*n^2+122*n-54)*a(n-3)-64*(n-5)*(n-4)*(13*n^2-49*n+42)*a(n-4)"
```

After

```
 ToString[strecur]
```

I get an absolutelly unusable output with exponents on separate lines.

[image]

So, my question is: How to convert it from a traditional format to a string (without changing the order of terms) ? Then it's easy to do StringReplace["string", " " -> "*"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a clear solution of my problem. After the conversion with `ToString`, the following program merges two lines with the exponents back to one line. Then is the final expression in the required format and it's possible to replace spaces with `*`.

```
 line1 = Characters[StringSplit[ToString[strecur], "\n"][[1]]];
 line2 = Characters[StringSplit[ToString[strecur], "\n"][[2]]];
 formula = ""; Do[If[k <= Length[line1], 
 If[line1[[k]] != " ", formula = formula <> "^" <> line1[[k]], 
 formula = formula <> line2[[k]];], 
 formula = formula <> line2[[k]];], {k, 1, Length[line2]}];
 formula = StringReplace[formula, "+ " -> "+"];
 formula = StringReplace[formula, " +" -> "+"];
 formula = StringReplace[formula, "- " -> "-"];
 formula = StringReplace[formula, " -" -> "-"];
 formula = StringReplace[formula, " " -> "*"]

 (* "2*(n-1)*(2*n-3)*(13*n^2-75*n+104)*a(n)=3*(117*n^4-1039*n^3+3315*n^2-4513*n+2216)*a(n-1)-12*(39*n^4-368*n^3+1268*n^2-1893*n+1032)*a(n-2)-16*(n-4)*(13*n^3-75*n^2+122*n-54)*a(n-3)-64*(n-5)*(n-4)*(13*n^2-49*n+42)*a(n-4)" *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line starting with `strpol` to

```
strpol = ToString[numpol*a[n - ord] /. Times -> Inactive[Times], TraditionalForm]
```

and you should get output like the following (click on the image to enlarge):

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for a good idea! Unfortunately we have in the output unwanted +-368 and +-1039

Comment: "+-" is in the variable `strpol` immediatelly after this statement. Maybe is a solution to replace "+-" -> "-" in the final string ?! I have to analyze whether this will always be right.

Answer (score -1):

The best way would be to convert `strecur` into a *Mathematica* expression

```
exrecur=ToExpression[StringReplace[strecur, "=" -> "=="]
```

You need to replace `"="` with `"=="` because you don't want to make an assignment. Next just convert it back to string using the `InputForm`

```
strecurInput = ToString[exrecur,InputForm]
```

Similarly as above you can replace back `"=="` with `"="` if you like to.

Comment: Your output is useless to me. The purpose of this program is to convert recurrence into a publishable format, in traditional format, with round brackets and normal operand order. InputForm changes the order. The polynomials are in the reverse order.

Comment: Sorry but that wasn't so clear from the question. Have you tried to use `TeXForm` on the Mathematica output (my `exrecur` to be clear). It should yield polynomials in the right order. Then all you have to do is copy it in LaTeX and compile it.